# I want to add client side validation on datatable editor

Tags: jquery, datatable

this is my code

```
"events": { 
            "onSubmitError":function (xhr, err, json, data) {
                console.log(err);
                $('#'+data.id).remove();
                editor.close();
                return false;
            },
            "onPreSubmit": function (o) {

            }

        }
```

I want to add validation on submit of the form only client side validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please use this code for client side validation in editor :

**browser** field name

```
if ( o.data.browser === "" ) {
                    this.error('browser', 'A browser must be given');
                    return false;
                }
                else if ( o.data.browser.length >= 10 ) {
                    this.error('browser', 'The browser name length must be less that 10 characters');
                    return false;
                }
                // ... etc
```

AND FOLLOW THIS LINK : [CLIENT SIDE VALIDATION IN DATA TABLE EDITOR](http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/clientValidation.html)